# Como clonar uma segunda branch usando o mesmo diretório da primeira branch clonada?

Tags: git

Tenho um repositório com várias branches, clonei uma específica e trabalhei nela.

Posteriormente surgiu a necessidade de trabalhar em outra branch desse mesmo projeto, tem como clonar ela para a mesma pasta da primeira branch ?

- Obs: como o repositório é muito grande, é muito demorado para clonar todo o projeto de uma vez.

Comment: Como você está gerenciando seus remotos? Você empurrou alguma coisa?

Comment: gitMerge? https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge

Comment: já realizei alguns push para a branch que clonei ... Eu não quero juntar as branches, só quero clonar mais uma na mesma pasta

Answer (score 1):

Sim.

1. Ponto de partida branch original -> develop

   ```
   >git status
   On branch develop
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
   ```
2. Criar primeira branch

   ```
   >git checkout -b feature/primeira-branch
   Switched to a new branch 'feature/primeira-branch'
   ```
3. Agora vc esta na primeira branch modifique algo, adicione e comite as alteracoes. Exemplo, criei um arquivo  `helloworld.txt`

   ```
   >notepad helloworld.txt

   >git status
   On branch feature/primeira-branch
   Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    helloworld.txt

   >git add .

   >git commit -m "Novo arquivo"
   [feature/primeira-branch a78c07d] Novo arquivo
   1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 helloworld.txt
   ```
4. Agora vamos para um novo branch continuando do estado que paramos no primeiro branch

   ```
   >git checkout -b feature/segundo-branch
   Switched to a new branch 'feature/segundo-branch'
   ```
5. Caso não deseje começar o segundo branch de onde parou no primeiro, volte para o develop ou o branch que deseja começar e crie seu branch ¦à partir desse ponto. Por exemplo, se eu desejo criar um terceiro branch começando de develop devo fazer assim:

   ```
   >git checkout develop
   Switched to branch 'develop'
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

   >git checkout -b feature/terceiro-branch
   Switched to a new branch 'feature/terceiro-branch'
   ```
6. Verificando a árvore de alterações, vou para o branch da segunda feature para mostrar o commit à frente do develop (git log prompt ou gitk com interface gráfica)

   ```
   >git checkout feature/segundo-branch
   Switched to branch 'feature/segundo-branch'

   >git log --oneline --graph
   * a78c07d (HEAD -> feature/segundo-branch, feature/primeira-branch) Novo arquivo
   * 69ccbd4 (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, feature/terceiro-branch, develop)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o comando, para trabalhar diretamente com a branch:

```
git checkout -b [branch] [nomeremoto]/[branch]
```

Ou caso queira criar outra branch e dar merge.

**Criando a branch:**

```
git branch nomebranch
```

**Dando um checkout:**

```
git checkout nomebranch
```

**Dando merge:**

```
git merge nomebanchdesjado
```

Comment: quando tento a primeira opção acontece o seguinte "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'teste' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/teste' which can not be resolved as commit?
", quando executo "git status" não aparece nenhuma modificação

Comment: Você tem esse branch teste no repositório origin?

Comment: Sim , tenho  ......

Comment: Mas seu repositório origin é o local? ou é o master?

Comment: é o remoto ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch tenta aplicar esses passos.